# friend declaration declares a non-template function, undefined reference

Tags: c++11, undefined-reference

I have such template class, which includes a friend method:

```cpp
template<class T1, class T2, int n>
class Graph final
{
private:
    std::array<T1, n> vertex;
    std::array<std::array<T2, n>, n> arcs;
public:
    Graph(const std::array<T1, n> & v, const std::array<std::array<T2, n>, n> & a);
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Graph<T1, T2, n> & g);
};
```

```cpp
template<class T1, class T2, int n>
Graph<T1, T2, n>::Graph(const std::array<T1, n> & v, const std::array<std::array<T2, n>, n> & a)
    : vertex(v)
{ ... }

template<class T1, class T2, int n>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Graph<T1, T2, n> & g)
{ ... }
```

This class is used to save graphs. Vertex is an array that stores nodes, and T1 is the corresponding element type. Arcs is a two-dimensional array of n * n that stores the path overhead between nodes, and T2 is the corresponding element type.(Note that n is the template non-type parameters.)

And I try to create a `Graph` and call friend method like this:

```cpp
void test() {
    using std::array;
    array<int, 5> vertex = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};

    array<int, 5> a = {2, 3, 2, 4, 5};
    array<array<int, 5>, 5> arcs = {a, a, a, a, a};

    Graph<int, int, 5> g(vertex, arcs);
    std::cout << g << std::endl;
}
```

Only get Error:

```
tree_mst.h:31:87: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& meyok::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Graph<T1, T2, n>&)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
         friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Graph<T1, T2, n> & g);
                                                                                       ^
tree_mst.h:31:87: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)

../lib/libmtree.so: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Graph<int, int, 5ull> const&)'
../lib/libmtree.so: undefined reference to `Graph<int, int, 5ull>::Graph(std::array<int, 5ul> const&, std::array<std::array<int, 5ul>, 5ul> const&)'
```

Why are warnings and errors popping up here. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: NO. In fact, these three files look like this: The Graph class is in tree_mst.h (containing #ifndef, #define statements), and its definition is in tree_mst.cpp (containing #include "tree_mst.h" statements) (both are packaged into dynamic libraries). The file of the test method has the #include "tree_mst.h" statement.

Comment: The dupe answers your question. Get rid of tree_mst.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `friend` declaration declares, for each instantiation of `Graph`, a regular non-template function named `operator<<` taking this instantiation as a parameter. For example, your program uses `Graph<int, int, 5>` - when the compiler first sees that, it produces a declaration

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Graph<int, int, 5>& g);
```

Note that this is separate and distinct from your `operator<<` function template.

Then the compiler sees `std::cout << g` and performs an overload resolution to select the best overload for `operator<<`. Since a non-template function is preferred over the function template, other things equal, the function introduced by `friend` declaration is selected. Finally, the linker discovers that this function is never actually implemented; hence the error.

Most likely, you meant to say a specialization of `operator<<` function template that matches the `Graph` template parameters should be the friend of that `Graph` specialization. You express it this way:

```
// Forward declaration
template<class T1, class T2, int n>
class Graph;

// Forward declaration
template<class T1, class T2, int n>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Graph<T1, T2, n> & g);

template<class T1, class T2, int n>
class Graph
{
public:
    friend std::ostream & operator<< <T1, T2, n>(std::ostream & os, const Graph<T1, T2, n> & g);
};
```

---

However, it's usually simpler to avoid `friend` altogether, and have `operator<<` delegate to a member function:

```
template<class T1, class T2, int n>
class Graph
{
public:
    void print(std::ostream& os) const { /* actual output logic here */);
};

template<class T1, class T2, int n>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Graph<T1, T2, n>& g) {
  g.print(os);
  return os;
}
```